# equivariant Serre Duality. 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular projective variety of dimension $n$ over a field $k$, and $\omega_X$ be its canonical sheaf.  Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of the automorphism group $Aut_k(X)$, and $\mathcal{F}$ a locally free $G$-equivariant sheaf on $X$.  Then $G$ acts on all the cohomology groups $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})$.  Is the Serre duality 
$$ H^i(X, \mathcal{F})\times H^{n-i}(X, \mathcal{F}^\vee\otimes \omega_X)\to H^n(X, \omega_X)=k$$ 
a $G$-equivariant perfect pairing? Where can I find a reference to this result?

Thank you.

Comment: The isomorphism $\mathrm H^n(X, \omega_X) \simeq k$ is universal, that is, invariant under isomorphisms. The universal pairing is functorial under pullbacks. The result follows from this.

Comment: @Angelo: Perhaps the OP seeks a reference to justify the invariance you mention? Many references on Serre duality make the construction of the trace in a manner that is not sufficiently intrinsic to render the triviality apparent. It is equivalent to show that the natural composite map $H^n(X,\Omega^n_{X/k}) \rightarrow H^n(X,g^{\ast}(\Omega^n_{X/k})) \rightarrow H^n(X,\Omega^n_{X/k})$ is the identity (1st step pullback, 2nd step canonical at sheaf level); settling projective spaces "by bare hands" is a bit unpleasant (though easy by using the structure of the automorphism group).

Comment: @nosr, I tried to prove what you suggested and indeed it is not too difficult.  However, I was trying to find a reference to include in a paper. 

Answer (score 3):

In a restricted situation you may consult

Peskin, Barbara R.
On the dualizing sheaf of a quotient scheme. 
*Comm. Algebra* **12** (1984), no. 15-16, pp. 1855–1869.

Of course, the general treatment is

Hashimoto, Mitsuyasu
Equivariant twisted inverses. in *Foundations of Grothendieck duality for diagrams of schemes*, pp. 261–478, Lecture Notes in Math., **1960**, Springer, Berlin, 2009.

but it requires a great deal of machinery, derived categories, etc.

Hope this is of some help